# Rollback is not working in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, odbc

I am using C# and MYSQL and the Rollback is not working.  I have three delete statement where the table third delete SQL don't exists and in catch i am doing rollback but its only happening for third while

```
         string id = dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
         string strDelete = "DELETE FROM user WHERE id = " + id;
         OdbcTransaction transaction = null;
         OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand();
         cmd.Connection = Singleton.Instance.GetConnection();
         transaction = Singleton.Instance.GetConnection().BeginTransaction();
         cmd.Transaction = transaction;
         try
         {
             cmd.CommandText = strDelete;
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
             // delete from userdata
             strDelete = "DELETE FROM userdata WHERE id = " + id;
             cmd.CommandText = strDelete;
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
             // delete from usersystem
             strDelete = "DELETE FROM usersystem WHERE id = " + id;
             cmd.CommandText = strDelete;
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
             // delete from user systemstatus. here table don't exists, will throw 
             // exception 
             strDelete = "DELETE FROM usersystemstatusAAAA WHERE id = " + id;
             cmd.CommandText = strDelete;
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
             transaction.Commit();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             // Attempt to roll back the transaction.
             try
             {
                 transaction.Rollback();
             }
             catch (Exception ex2)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine("  Message: {0}", ex2.Message);
             }

         }
```

Here the first two SQL statements are committed while suppose to rollback all.

Comment: Are you using MyISAM or InnoDB as storage engine? Does a rollback work when you execute it in SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check the storage type of your MySQL database. Not all storages are transactional. For example InnoDB has transactions while MyISAM does not.

MyISAM versus InnoDB
[MyISAM versus InnoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148/myisam-versus-innodb)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you have a second connection, and there is confusion over the connection/transaction/command; try starting the transaction on the connection you are actually using instead:

```
cmd.Connection = Singleton.Instance.GetConnection();
transaction = cmd.Connection.BeginTransaction();
```

also, you might want to look at `using` blocks here.

Comment: @CrazyC well... as per the other comments... is your storage actually transactional?

Comment: sorry to ask, how can i check it?

Comment: @CrazyC then Jeno has the answer; it does not support transactions